# Smallest Rectangular Box that surrounds a polyhedron

Tags: computational-geometry, polyhedra, geometry-class-library

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds the smallest box enclosing a polyhedron.

My idea is as follows: find the largest side, and move the solid so that side aligns with the x axis. Find the next largest side that meets this side, and align it as close as possible to the z axis, while leaving the other side on x.
Then, calculate the greatest differences in x, y and z. Use those dimensions to create the surrounding shape and then shift the box back to the object's original location.

Is there a more efficient strategy for this?
Does my idea overlook some corner cases?

Edit: For now assume the object to be bounded is convex. Though, an answer for the general case would also be welcome.

Comment: Don't think there's enough information here. For example, are the polyhedra restricted to convex figures, or can they be arbitrarily complex and twisty? Does the bounding box need to be axis-aligned, or can it be rotated? I'm not entirely convinced that, in the general case, a minimal bounding box will have one face coplanar with a face of the polyhedron, although it does seem likely...

Comment: Let's assume for now that the object to be bounded is convex.

Comment: what is "smallest"? least voluminous?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding minimal (volume) boxes for convex polyhedrons has been studied by O'Rourke, who proposes an `O(n^3)` algorithm:

> J. O-Rourke. Finding minimal enclosing boxes. International Journal of
>   Computer & Information Sciences, 1985, 14(3), p.183.

O'Rourke's algorithm finds the minimal enclosing box for a set of points in `R^3` -- but this is clearly equivalent to finding the enclosing box for the polyhedron formed as the convex hull of the underlying point-set.

Contrary to what one might expect (and the approach you've described, if I've understood you correctly), the minimal box is not necessarily oriented such that a face of the polyhedron is coplanar with a face of the box! Note the animation shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms) for a simple tetrahedron.

If you're happy with the idea of simply find an enclosing box that's relatively small, rather than *the* smallest enclosing box, there may be other (faster) heuristics that can be applied...

Comment: For my purposes, relatively small is good enough. It doesn't have to be the absolute smallest.